# What is the best way to write a string buffer for socket IO in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, buffer

I have a thread that runs a non-blocking event loop and other threads can put strings on a buffer for the event loop to write to a socket.

I want to accumulate the strings in a buffer, so that multiple small strings can be sent using one call to `send`.

Conceptually, the buffer needs to do 3 things.

1. get a chunk of data from the start of the buffer
2. add data to the end of the buffer
3. free the first n bytes of the buffer

I cosidered a few things.

- `StringIO` would be really suitable for writing strings to the end, but no way to free data after it's written to the socket.
- `collections.deque` of bytes. Very memory inefficient.
- `array.array` Easy to append strings. Copying slices for reading/dumping data.

My current code looks like this, but I'm not super happy with the copying and locking.

```
from array import array
from threading import Condition

class SendBuffer(object):

    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self.mark = 0
        self.buf = array('c')
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.full = Condition()

    def __len__(self):
        with self.full:
            return len(self.buf) - self.mark


    def write(self, data):
        with self.full:
            while len(self) >= self.max_size:
                # wait until data is written
                self.full.wait()

            self.buf.fromstring(data)

    def _peek(self):
        return buffer(self.buf, self.mark)

    def _written(self, n):
        self.mark += n
        self.full.notify_all()

        if self.mark >= len(self.buf):
            self.mark = 0
            self.buf = array('c')
        elif self.mark >= self.max_size:
            self.buf = self.buf[self.mark:]
            self.mark = 0

    def to_sock(self, sock):
        with self.full:
            data = self._peek()
            if data:
                n = sock.send(data)
                self._written(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your buffers, like StringIO, are only efficient to append to. Instead of appending to the end and deleting from the front when you're done processing, do the following:

- Get two buffers.
- At any one moment, all writes will go to (the end of) one of them, and the reader will read from the other (using an index to keep position if the buffer is larger than want can be written out in one send() call).
- When the reader is done reading one buffer, the buffer is cleared(*) and they swap roles.

Let's consider some cases:

- The reader outpaces the writer(s): every write is immediately followed by a read of the same size, and the buffers swap position. Every write immediately goes out as a single packet.
- The readers and writers are exactly in sync, or close enough with some jitter: multiple small writes get accumulated into the write buffer until the reader is done, and then they get sent out in chunks as large as the network will take.
- The writer(s) outpace the reader. The write buffer will fill up while the reader is busy processing the read buffer. The reader will still send out as large chunks as the network will take, but you'll need to cap the writers in some way (typically by setting a maximum buffer size) and moderate them to avoid eating up limitless amounts of memory.

Remember that buffers are only a way to prevent stalling due to jitter. They don't help against mismatched producer/consumer speeds. In reality, your buffers will either be constantly full or constantly empty.

(*) Clearing a StringIO object is apparently not trivial, Google around a bit. You may want to create a new object instead of clearing, but that might lead to a lot of garbage which will need to be GC'ed if you have lots of context switches. Instead, you might also consider building your own clearable buffer using a combination of an array and an `index` variable, in which case clearing would come down to `index = 0`.

Comment: Ah! double buffering! Clearing the StringIO is as simple as seek(0). In order to limit the size of the buffer, you'll have to keep track of the length anyway, so you can use that to read only current data.

Comment: There is one issue with this method. Say my buffer is 100 bytes long and I write 99 to the socket, now I have a possibly full backbuffer, and a frontbuffer that will write one byte the next time the socket is ready.

Comment: That's a good point. On the hand, since we have a dynamic buffer, and the only goal is to reduce limitless buffer growth (not to cap the memory usage at an exact number of bytes), you could just have a simple rule like "allow writes if len(buffer) < N". Yes, the buffer could accidentally grow to "N + max_write_size", but if those numbers are reasonable that is probably not a real problem.

Comment: I ended up getting the buffer size of the underlying socket, so that in almost all cases the whole buffer can be written at once to the socket. No String copying and slicing in the common case. Unless the writie is larger than the max buffer size, I don't allow the buffer to grow even a single byt beyond the max size. Doing that made it extremely common that the buffer would contain N+10 bytes, of which N got written to the socket..